# why am I getting Run time error 1001 while Hiding Column

Tags: runtime-error

I am getting Run time error 1004 "Select method of Range class failed.
The following code I am using in another file and is working well. Why should I get run time error now, is my question.

My code:

```
Private Sub CommButton_WMA20_Click()
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    Sheets("A3-Graph").Select
    Columns("AF:AF").Select
    
    If Selection.EntireColumn.Hidden = True Then
        Selection.EntireColumn.Hidden = False
        CommButton_WMA20.BackColor = 11583693
        Else
        Selection.EntireColumn.Hidden = True
        CommButton_WMA20.BackColor = 16776960
    End If
    
    Range("A10").Select
    Range("O11").Select
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

Comment: That would depend, at least in part, on what language this is, and what the difference between these 2 files is.